# How can I databind in the _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET WebForms, I can use the CodeBehind of a master page to fetch data to use to bind up my navigation.

**How can I achieve the same in ASP.NET MVC 3?**

Ideally the main navigation would be in the `_Layout.cshtml` but this file doesn't have it's own model. i.e. It can only use the model supplied by the controller action (assuming a base class and `@model` directive in the `_Layout.cshtml`.

**Edit**
While I realise MVC does not have the notion of DataBinding, I included it here to help describe the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: +1, but when I was returning View(..) I got overflow exception, hence I have chnaged into PartialView(..) and it works!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I achieve the same in ASP.NET MVC 3?

The notion of databinding is not common for the MVC pattern. To implement the navigation you could use [Html.Action and Html.RenderAction](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).

Example:

```
public class NavigationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        NavigationViewModel model = ...
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and then inside the layout:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Navigation")
```

The index.cshtml could be a partial which implements the navigation.